# How can I connect PHP to Bluemix database?

Tags: php, database, ibm-cloud

I have an php file, and I want to connect it to Database
usually I use localhost but I never use php in [Bluemix](http://bluemix.net) 
what should I fill these attributes ?

```
$DB_HOST = 'localhost'; // what should I write instead of 
$DB_USER = '';
$DB_PASSWORD = '';
$DB_DATABASE = 'MyDataBase';
```

please help

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

**First:** You Create a folder **`.bp-config/options.json`** in the parent folder

and add below line, of code in the `options.json` folder, so `sqli` connect will working.

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
}
```

Now make a connection:

```
$DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1:3307';  // insert ip with port number 
$DB_USER = 'user';
$DB_PASSWORD = 'password';
$DB_DATABASE = 'dbname';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_DATABASE);
$result = $mysqli->query(" SELECT * FROM table_name ");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I inset my ip and what should I write for $DB_user, is writing 'user' enough or I should write my information ?

Comment: dude use your credentials. :D

Comment: thank you for helping, and I am sorry for being late, but I really do not know which user or password they are talking about ? do they mean my account on Bluemix or something else ?

Comment: @user3880907, your **`VCAP_SERVICES_credentials`**.

Answer (score 1):

Create your database service on Bluemix and BIND it to your application. Go to your applications dashboard and you should see the database service instance below. Click on Show Credentials.
[image]

However, the right way to do this is to programmatically get the credentials by parsing the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. See this example:
https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/php-mysql  See db.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse db information from VCAP_SERVICES.

If your database service is "SQL Database" you can connect to SQLDB using this example code:

```
//parse VCAP_SERVICES Environment variable
$vcap_services = $_ENV["VCAP_SERVICES"];
$services_json = json_decode($vcap_services,true);
$sqldb = $services_json["sqldb"];
if (empty($sqldb)) {
    echo "No sqldb service instance is bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance";
    return;
}

//Get Credentials object (db,host,port,username,password)
$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
   $sqldb_config["db"].
   ";HOSTNAME=".
   $sqldb_config["host"].
   ";PORT=".
   $sqldb_config["port"].
   ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
   $sqldb_config["username"].
   ";PWD=".
   $sqldb_config["password"].
   ";";


$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', ''); //db connection
```